# PHP Slim GET request with BLOB variable

Tags: php, mysql, blob, slim

I'm trying to execute a fetch request in `PHP Slim framework`. But There's a `BLOB` variable in my `MYSQL` database. Which contains `array` of `strings`. How do I retrieve `BLOB` variable and convert it back into `array` of `strings`.

Here's my fetch method

```
// fetch all apps
$app->get('/apps', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM app ORDER BY updated_at");
    $sth->execute();
    $apps = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $this->response->withJson($apps);
});
```

here`$apps` have a variable named `locale` which is `BLOB`. I want to return `$apps` with `array` of `strings`

Comment: How is the array of strings stored into the blob? What is the JSON output with the current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong. I was trying to save `Array` object direct into the `BLOB`. Due to which on retrieving it, I was getting a string "Array" instead of my `Array` data.

Now, I'm encoding the `array` in to `JSON String`, and then saving it into `BLOB` variable.

and on retrieving it, I'm decoding the `string` back to `JSON`.

This is how I'm saving app

```
// add new app
$app->post('/saveApp', function ($request, $response) {
    $input = $request->getParsedBody();
    $input['locale'] = json_encode($input['locale']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO app (id,name,locale) VALUES (:id,:name,:locale)";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam("id", $input['id']);
    $sth->bindParam("name", $input['name']);
    $sth->bindParam("locale", $input['locale']);
    $sth->execute();
    $input['id'] = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    return $this->response->withJson($input);
});
```

This is how I'm fetching apps

```
// fetch all apps
$app->get('/apps', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM app ORDER BY updated_at");
    $sth->execute();
    $apps = $sth->fetchAll();
        $result = array();
        foreach ($apps as $app) {
            $app['locale'] = json_decode($app['locale']);
            array_push($result, $app);
        }
    return $this->response->withJson($result);
});
```